# Json Request on web/http protocol in loadrunner

Tags: json, http, protocols, loadrunner

i need to send json payload to a given URL usin web/http protocol. I have a web url and a payload only.

how do i send the request ?

Thanks a lot in advance

pushpak

Answer (score 1):

Something like this to send login credentials to myUrl:

```
web_custom_request("myUrl",
"URL=http://myUrl.com",
"Method=POST",
"RecContentType=application/json",
"Body="
"{"
"\"name\":\"myName\"m\,"
"\"password\":\"myPassword\""
"}"
LAST);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you recorded the JSON conversation with VUGEN to see what it looks like?